# Zero-byte audio file uploaded after recording from WordPress frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, audio, upload

I'm working on a WordPress site where I need to record audio from the frontend and upload it to the server upon stopping the recording. The recording and uploading processes seem to work, but the uploaded file always ends up being 0 bytes. I'm using JavaScript for recording and handling the blob, and PHP for uploading.

Here's a simplified overview of my setup:

JavaScript (audio.js):

I use getUserMedia to record audio and MediaRecorder for handling the recording. When the recording stops, I create a blob from the recorded chunks and attempt to upload it using fetch.

```
let mediaRecorder;
let audioChunks = [];

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
  .then(stream => {

    const mimeType = MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('audio/mp3') ? 'audio/mp3' : 'audio/webm';
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType });

    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = event => {
      audioChunks.push(event.data);
    };

    mediaRecorder.onstop = () => {
      const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: mimeType });
      const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
      document.querySelector("#audioPreview").src = audioUrl;
    };
  });

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  document.querySelector("#startRecord").addEventListener("click", () => {
    mediaRecorder.start();
    document.querySelector("#startRecord").disabled = true;
    document.querySelector("#stopRecord").disabled = false;
    audioChunks = [];
  });

document.querySelector("#stopRecord").addEventListener("click", () => {
    mediaRecorder.stop();
    document.querySelector("#startRecord").disabled = false;
    document.querySelector("#stopRecord").disabled = true;
  });
});

//upload file random name
function generateFilename(postID) {
    const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    
    // Generar 3 caracteres aleatorios para el inicio
    let startRandomString = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        startRandomString += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length));
    }
    return startRandomString ;
}


document.querySelector("#stopRecord").addEventListener("click", () => {
  mediaRecorder.stop();
  // uploadfile
  let postID = document.querySelector("#startRecord").getAttribute("data-postid");

  const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: 'audio/mp3' });
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('action', 'upload_audio'); // same name hook functions.php
formData.append('audioFile', audioBlob,  generateFilename(postID));
  fetch(AudioRecorderAjax.url, { // URL from PHP
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
  })
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
});
```

PHP (functions.php):

```
$dirlib = 'lib0';

//Enqueue my js and admin-post
function enqueue_audio_recorder_script() {
    global $dirlib;
    wp_enqueue_script('audio-recorder', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/'.$dirlib.'/audio.js', array(), null, true);

    wp_localize_script('audio-recorder', 'AudioRecorderAjax', array(
        'url' => admin_url('admin-post.php'),
        'postID' => $post_id 
    ));}    

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_audio_recorder_script');

/*shortcode*/
function audioupload_shortcode() {
        $post_id = isset($post) ? $post->ID : 0;

    $html = '<button id="startRecord" data-postid="'.esc_attr($post_id).'">Iniciar Grabación</button>
             <button id="stopRecord" disabled>Detener Grabación</button>
             <audio id="audioPreview" controls></audio>';

    return $html;
}
add_shortcode('audioupload', 'audioupload_shortcode');

/*upload audio*/
function handle_audio_upload() {
    if (isset($_FILES['audioFile'])) {

        $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $upload_path = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . basename($_FILES['audioFile']['name']);


        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['audioFile']['tmp_name'], $upload_path)) {

            echo 'success';
        } else {
            echo 'error';
        }
    }
    wp_die(); 
}

add_action('admin_post_nopriv_upload_audio', 'handle_audio_upload'); 
add_action('admin_post_upload_audio', 'handle_audio_upload');
```

I enqueue the JS script and handle the audio file upload in a WordPress environment. The PHP script is supposed to receive the file and move it to the uploads directory.

What could be causing the recorded audio data not to be captured or uploaded correctly, resulting in a 0-byte file on the server? Are there any common pitfalls in this process when working with WordPress and JavaScript?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!